# Python: Error raised for scripts saved on server

Tags: python, operating-system, python-imaging-library, easygui

I'm hoping this is a simple issue and I'm just missing something. I have a script saved in two different locations, on our shared server and locally on my desktop. When I run the script from the server I get what appears to be easygui error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "Z:\Python\module1.py", line 35, in <module>
      reply = buttonbox(msg=msg,image=IMG)
TypeError: buttonbox() got an unexpected keyword argument 'msg'
```

This I can get around. For some reason, message is required for the version that is saved on the server and msg is required for the version saved on my desktop. That is ok since it at least works. What breaks this for me is the image feature. It works in the version on my desktop but I have no idea how to get it to work on the version on our server. Full code shown below:

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image
import os
from easygui import *
import sys
print sys.version, sys.version_info

WORKDIR = "c:\\temp"
DESKTOP = 'c:' + os.environ['HOMEPATH'] + "\Desktop"
os.chdir(DESKTOP)
IMAGES = os.listdir(DESKTOP+"\\New Items Images")
for IMAGE in IMAGES:

path = DESKTOP+"\\New Items Images\\"+IMAGE

#Creates a Tkinter-compatible photo image, which can be used everywhere Tkinter expects an image object.
img = Image.open(path)
width, height = img.size
if width >= height:
    basewidth = 600
    wpercent = (basewidth / float(img.size[0]))
    hsize = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
else:
    baseheight = 600
    hpercent = (baseheight / float(img.size[1]))
    wsize = int((float(img.size[0]) * float(hpercent)))
img = img.resize((basewidth, hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)

img.save(DESKTOP + "\\" + IMAGE)


IMG = DESKTOP+"\\"+IMAGE
SKU = "sku"
msg = "Is %s acceptable?\n%s\n%sx%s" % (IMAGE, SKU, width, height)
reply = buttonbox(msg=msg,image=IMG)
if ynbox == 1:
    print "This would now get pushed to CA"
```

`
Generally speaking I know that this is probably ugly code. But that aside, what the end game goal here is to open an image, display it to the user, then delete all created imaged from desktop. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry, I dont know exactly what you mean. The server I mentioned is only used to store the script. It isn't even actually being executed by the server.

Comment: Forget my previous comments which were out of topic . First thing is that you might want to use `os.path.join` for folders instead of backslashes. Then could you try to print a call to `os.path.exist` with `IMG` to check what the servers say?

Comment: os.path.exists(IMG) comes back True for os.path.join and the way I had it originally. It's just weird because it seems like the the "image=" stops working once I save the script to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps its the way its imported and its picking up buttonbox from another library and not recognising the parameters.

does this work?

```
import easygui
easygui.buttonbox(msg=msg, image=IMG)
```

or even plain data like this work?

```
import easygui
easygui.buttonbox('Click on your favorite flavor.', 'Favorite Flavor', ('Chocolate', 'Vanilla', 'Strawberry'))
```

if neither of those work you might want to check the version of easygui and the documentation related.

or perhaps its a conflict with the class "ButtonBox" and instantiation function "buttonbox" they have that are named the same except one doesn't use kwargs and for some reason there is an issue there.

https://github.com/robertlugg/easygui/blob/master/easygui/boxes/button_box.py#L110

try instantiate a class version like this

```
bb = ButtonBox("message", "title", ('Chocolate', 'Vanilla'), None, None, None, None)
reply = bb.run()
```

Comment: No luck with that. I changed import to import easygui and changed buttonbox to easygui.bottonbox. Unfortunately, same thing. Worked in the file saved locally but not in file saved on my server. Thank you though. I appreciate it.

Comment: What python version and what version of easygui is it? and is easygui installed correctly on the server python?

Comment: I've verified python as 2.7.13 and .98.1 for both the server and my PC.

Comment: yea its strange as the error you are reporting as coming back is more of an interface issue not expecting a keyword. I've added something else to my answer you can try, creating it from the class instead